# Not sure how to hide information with a 0 value

Tags: javascript, xml, action

I just need an event or action for my code to not show information when the value is "0" please. typically when the value is greater than 1 it shows the XML information and even when X is choosen it shows previous XML data but I would like it to be empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>

<form>
<select id="pullDownList" onchange="myFunction();">
<option value="0">Please Choose a Country</option>

<script>

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
 else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","./cords_data.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


var xmlDocument=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
for (i=0;i<xmlDocument.length;i++)
{
document.write("<option value='");
document.write(i+1);
document.write("'>");
document.write(xmlDocument[i].getElementsByTagName("Country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
</script></select>
<p />

<div id=fieldInfo1></div>
<div id=fieldInfo2></div>
<div id=fieldInfo3></div>
<div id=fieldInfo4></div>
</p>

 <script>

function myFunction()


var z = document.getElementById("pullDownList").selectedIndex-1;
if (pullDownList.value == "0"){



}else {

document.getElementById("fieldInfo1").innerHTML = xmlDocument[z].getElementsByTagName("Country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("fieldInfo2").innerHTML = xmlDocument[z].getElementsByTagName("Voltage")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("fieldInfo3").innerHTML = xmlDocument[z].getElementsByTagName("Freq__Hz")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("fieldInfo4").innerHTML = xmlDocument[z].getElementsByTagName("Cord_Designator")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;






}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
if (document.getElementById("tagThatHoldsValueOfZero").innerHTML == "0") {

 document.getElementById("tagThatHoldsValueOfZero).style.display = "none";
}
```

Using `.innerHTML` will get the content/text of that element.

Comment: and then the XML stuff should just go in the else under that?

Comment: Correct. I'm not sure when you want this event to fire (ie: on page load, button click, field change, etc...) but in my eyes, on page load, you would want to check for the zero values then execute what you want to happen for those fields. So yea, the `else` statement should cover it.